# GWT - Time displayed is 1 hour later than the time stored in the DB

Tags: mysql, gwt

When I display the time on the client side it is one hour later than that stored on the database (I am only storing the time in MySQL as time type). I fond this solution:

```
            Calendar myCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            int gmtOffset = myCalendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
            int tzOffsetMin = (myCalendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + myCalendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET))/(1000*60);
            Window.alert("gmtOffset = " + gmtOffset + " tzOffsetMin = " + tzOffsetMin);
```

However, when I compile it I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Glyndwr/workspace/AwardTracker_N/src/org/AwardTracker/client/HikeDetailsView.java'
      [ERROR] Line 525: No source code is available for type java.util.Calendar; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 525: No source code is available for type java.util.GregorianCalendar; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I found that this is a known issue with GWT.

So how do I find the offset in GWT so I can allow for it? If I simply subtract one hour then this is not going to be correct when we move from daylight savings time to normal time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client TZ setting in your browser may affect it, as well as the TZ of your server JVM. If you want the Date to be displayed in the exact same TZ as in database, store it as string, in any pattern really, Let's say 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' will do.
Then de-serialize it with DateTimeFormat on client.

That's what we did when we've encountered 2 different transformations (JVM and then client browser) with our dates. I hope it helps.

Comment: This approach only works if you plan to display the same time to all of your users, regardless in which time zone they currently are.

Comment: Hi Andrei, yes I do plan to display the time exactly as entered regardless of the time zone they are in.

Answer (score 0):

GWT compiler doesn't support `java.util.Calendar` class, that's why you are getting above error. To deal with such date, time and timezone issue I will suggest to go through following steps

1. I will recommend to use [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) or store time(miliseconds) of your date object in database.
2. Fetch this value from database,pass Date( or miliseconds time) value through rpc call.
3. Final step will be to display time part of Date object using  [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) formatting methods, by default it will consider client/browsers timezone and will show value accordingly.

Comment: `Date` object does not have any time zone information.

Comment: True, we can club step 2& 3

Answer (score 0):

You can get offset information from `TimeZone` class.

```
TimeZone.createTimeZone(String tzJSON)
```

Fromt GWT documentation:

> Applications can get such a string from the TimeZoneConstants class,
>   or it can request the string from the server. Either way, the
>   application obtains the original string from the data provided in the
>   TimeZoneConstant.properties file, which was carefully prepared from
>   CLDR and Olson time zone database.

You typically do not want all of these Strings on your client. I use an RPC call to retrieve only the string that I need.

Note that time zone offset may be different on different dates.